# Retrieving data from xlsx using OleDb(C#), how to get the count of lines in the xlsx?

Tags: c#, oledb, xlsx

My final goal is to retrieve the data from .xlsx file and load them into .mdb (Microsoft Access) file. My code is now like this:

```
    String fileName = "1.xlsx";
    OleDbConnection conn = new OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;" + "Data Source=" + fileName + ";" + ";Extended Properties=\"Excel 12.0;HDR=YES;IMEX=1\"");
    conn.Open();
    DataTable dtSheetName = conn.GetOleDbSchemaTable(OleDbSchemaGuid.Tables, new object[] { null, null, null, "TABLE" });
    string cmdText = "SELECT * FROM [sheet1$A3:B3]";
    DataSet ds;
    using (OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand(cmdText))
    {
        cmd.Connection = conn;
        OleDbDataAdapter adpt = new OleDbDataAdapter(cmd);
        ds = new DataSet();
        adpt.Fill(ds, "sheet1");
    }
```

But this is when I know how many lines are there in the sheet. What if I don't know about this information? Can I somehow manage to know how many lines are there in the sheet?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

change the line

```
 string cmdText = "SELECT * FROM [sheet1$A3:B3]";
```

to

```
string cmdText = "SELECT * FROM [sheet1$]";
```

and add the following line to at the end of your code.

```
int numberOfRows = ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count;
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to assign columns and rows. You cold just do something like:

```
string cmdText = "SELECt * FROM [sheet1$]"
```

Or if you want to limit which columns to read:

```
string cmdText = "SELECt * FROM [sheet1$A1:B100000]"
```

Edit: Sorry, missed the part about needing to know how many rows there are. cilerler has your answer.